# Image overlay turning on before mouse goes over the image

Tags: css, mousehover

I would like to understand why when I place my mouse anywhere on the page, the hover effect applies to the image, instead of activating when the mouse is placed directly on the image itself. I've tried changing the width and height of the main container, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

```
<https://codepen.io/jl88s/pen/oawOOM?editors=1100>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal viable code snippet using the tools available. Feel free to post a working link to codepen with a code snippet in the question itself. StackOverlow also allows for a tool to get a runnable snippet, which in a lot of cases remove the need for codepen.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution causes another problem. The overlay disappears when you try to hover button. Sorry about that. Check my new solution.

Here is the css :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
}

.middle {
    transition: 2s ease;
    position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.container:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you set the `:hover` selector on your container, which takes the full height and width. So at the moment you enter the window, the `:hover` is triggered.

Set your container to `display: inline-flex`, remove the `height` and then postion the container where you need it relatively to its 
parent.

Didn't add a parent, and did not position the container in the example, tell me if you want me to.

**Edit**

Added the centering in [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxrzjR?editors=1100) example. (See html and body styles)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
}

.middle {
    transition: 2s ease;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```